# cpanel error code 128 (Connection refused when cloning private repo)

Tags: cpanel

I'm trying to add a private github repository to my cpanel host but this error hapens to me:

> Error: (XID uaxnz3) “/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/git” reported
> error code “128” when it ended: ssh: connect to host github.com port
> 22: Connection refused fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
> exists.

I have added the Deploy key to private repository by the help of [this guide (click here)](https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/web-services/guide-to-git-set-up-access-to-private-repositories/).